# Unexpected stretched texture

Tags: opengl-es, textures, webgl

I have the following code snippets:

```
    ctx.texParameteri(ctx.TEXTURE_2D, ctx.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, ctx.LINEAR);      
    ctx.texParameteri(ctx.TEXTURE_2D, ctx.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, ctx.LINEAR);

    ctx.texParameteri(ctx.TEXTURE_2D, ctx.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, ctx.REPEAT);
    ctx.texParameteri(ctx.TEXTURE_2D, ctx.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, ctx.REPEAT);
```

My texture dimension is **256x256**.

**Option 1** -- my polygon

```
    const x0 = 100;
const x1 = -x0;
const z0 = x0;
const z1 = -z0;
var vertices = new Float32Array(
    [  x0, 0, z1,  x1, 0, z1,  x1, 0, z0,   x0, 0, z0]);
```

The result: The texture is stretched so I lose the detail.

**Option 2** -- my polygon (notice that this is a much smaller polygon than option 1)

```
const x0 = 5;
const x1 = -x0;
const z0 = x0;
const z1 = -z0;
var vertices = new Float32Array(
    [  x0, 0, z1,  x1, 0, z1,  x1, 0, z0,   x0, 0, z0]);
```

The result: I can see the details of my texture.

My understanding is that the REPEAT (TEXTURE_WRAP_S and TEXTURE_WRAP_T) option will give me the details even in Option 1. Why is the texture stretched in option 1? Did I misunderstand it?

This is running WebGL on Chrome Canary build.

What did I do wrong?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Are you setting the texture coordinates for the vertices and using them in your shader?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my texture coordinate to the following:

Code:
   var texCoords = new Float32Array(
//            [  1, 1,   0, 1,   0, 0,   1, 0]
            [  100, 100,   -100, 100,   -100, -100,   100, -100]
       );

It matches the big polygon coordinate. It shows the details of the original small texture on the big polygon.

Please see [Khronos WebGL Forum](http://www.khronos.org/message_boards/viewtopic.php?f=43&t=3338&p=8821&hilit=unexpected#p8821) for more detailed discussion